# Flutter Android Nav Bar blinks in white color using Google APIs

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-billing

I have a dark themed Flutter app with a dark system nav bar. Phone is in dark mode too.

When Google's Apis are used and overlay a dialog, they can alter the color of the navigation bar. Is there anyway to prevent this?

With Google Sign In, the nav bar goes white and then reverts, it's not *optimal* but it's acceptable. But using Google Billing, after dismissing the dialog, the nav bar blinks in white and it's very frustrating. Other apps (native) have this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code?

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.renderView.automaticSystemUiAdjustment = false;
```

Comment: I found that solution in [this Flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40590), but it's not working for the Billing Api. Anyway, I think it's great to have it as an answer as it may help other.